# How to install mixOmics packages in R version 4.0.0?

Tags: package, installation, version, pls, r-4.0.0

I have tried install package *mixOmics* but failed.

The output at console below:

> ```sh
> install.packages("mixOmics")
> Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
>   package ‘mixOmics’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
> ```

I have also tried it at R version 3.5.2 and still failed.

May you help me please

Comment: It is removed now from Cran, do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

Mixomics install is now only available through Bioconductor.

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/mixOmics.html